# Make Batch Inserts without auto increment in Java

Tags: java, postgresql

So I recently startet reading about sql best practices and found out about using Batch Statements for inserts and updates. So wanted to update some code using my new learned knowledge. For example I have a loop like this:

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false)

try {
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into TEST (ID,STR_TEST1) values (?,?)")

    for (String element : someList) {
        stmt.setInt(1, ???)
        stmt.setString(2, element)
    }
    stmt.executeBatch();
    conn.commit()
} finally {
    stmt.close()
}
```

Now unfortunately my tables don't auto increment ids and I can't change that for some reasons, what means, that I have to always select the next "free" id in my table. Problem with this is, it doesn't work, I guess because auto commit is set to false. Any ideas how to combat my problems? I thought about making sub-selects in my insert query, but I fear that this will weaken the performance.

Comment: If this is one big transaction you could do just one select before the loop and increment that value instead of selecting each time.

Comment: Why don't you create a sequence and use that in the `insert` statement?

Comment: @BackSlash Wouldn't that be kind of unsafe? I mean counting the alue up myself.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can you give me an example of how to create a sequence, I'm still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequence is the safest and fastest way to generate unique numbers (PostgreSQL's "auto increment" types `serial` or `identity` use that in the background).

To use it, [create one first](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html):

```
create sequence test_id_seq;
```

If you already have rows in the target table, adjust the sequence to return values greater than the current maximum:

```
select setval('test_id_seq', (select max(id) from test));
```

Then inside your INSERT statement use `nextval('test_id_seq')` instead of supplying a value:

```
try {
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement( 
      "insert into TEST (ID,STR_TEST1) values (setval('test_id_seq'),?)")

    for (String element : someList) {
        stmt.setString(1, element)
    }
    stmt.executeBatch();
    conn.commit()
} finally {
    stmt.close()
}
```